# WF4 SendReply to Receive in another activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm new to WF4 and was wondering if it was possible to send a reply to a receive activity defined in another workflow?

Once my WCF service receives a request I'm performing an operation in another activity and under certain conditions I want to send a reply to the request from this activity and then pause the workflow for further input. Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No that won't work. The Receive and the SendReply need to be linked to each other using an activity correlation handle.

What you can do however is use duplex communications where the second workflow sends a SOAP message to an endpoint with an address passed to it in the first message. Technically these are two separate requests and not related so there are no restrictions.